# How to update values from the specified indices in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, scatter

I have two tensors, the first one `A` has a shape `(B, N, 2)`, where `N` stands for the number and `2` stands for the indices. Another one `B` has a shape `(B, N, 3)`, `3` is the specified values. I want to scatter `B`'s values corresponding to `A` to a shape `(B, H, W, 3)`. For example,

```py
B = [[[1 1]
      [0 2]]

     [[1 1]
      [1 2]]]
A = [[[1 1 1]
      [2 0 1]]

     [[0 9 8]
      [9 1 2]]]
```

Through my thought, the final tensor with shape `(2, 2, 2, 3)` would be

```py
[[
    [
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [2, 0, 1]
    ],
    [
        [0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 0]
    ]
], [
    [
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]
    ],
    [
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 9, 8],
        [9, 1, 2]
    ]
]]
```

Except for those indices specified in `A`, other positions will be set to zeros. Are there any solutions to tackle this problem?

Comment: your final tensor is (2, 2, 3, 3) not (2, 2, 2, 3)

Comment: it is not clear - how to get your final from your A, B. I see that you are scattering from A based on indices in B. But I can not identify a pattern